# Creating nested route app in angular using angular-ui-router and switching between modules

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-providers

I want to create angular nested routes in my application using `angular-ui-router` with multi sub-modules;

In "`ui-router`" we can use multi views in our main app config as `$stateProvider`, but can't switch between sub-modules when you are in other module.

For example when you are in "`module1`" you can not state to "`module2`".

So, How can I switch between my modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this application you can route between sub modules easily:

1. Create main application "`mainApp.js`"

   ```js
   angular.module("mainApp", [
     "ui.router"
   ]);

   angular.module("mainApp").config([
     "$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider",
     function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

       $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

       $stateProvider
         .state("/", {
           url: "/",
           templateUrl: "/Application/Partials/home.html"
         });
     }
   ]);
   ```
2. Create "`index.html`" for your mainApp:

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html ng-app="mainApp">

   <head>
     <title>Angular Nested Routes with angula-ui-route</title>
   </head>

   <body>
     <fieldset>
       <legend>main menu</legend>
       <a ui-sref="/">home</a>
     </fieldset>

     <ui-view></ui-view>

     <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
     <script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
     <script src="/Scripts/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

     <!--Main Module-->
     <script src="/Application/app.js"></script>
   </body>

   </html>
   ```
3. Create your Partials "`home.html`"

   ```html
   <h1>Home</h1>
   ```
4. Add "`registerStateApp`" in your project

```js
angular.module("registerStateApp", []);
angular.module("registerStateApp").provider("$registerState", function ($stateProvider) {
    var routes = [];

    this.$set = function (stateProvider) {
        var satetProviders = {
            states: stateProvider
        }

        routes.push(satetProviders);
    };

    this.$get = function () {
        return angular.forEach(routes, function (route) {
            angular.forEach(route.states, function (state) {
                $stateProvider.state(state.state, {
                    parent: state.parent,
                    moduleName: parent,
                    stateName: child,
                    name: state.pageName,
                    url: state.url,
                    views: state.views,
                    pageInfo: state.pageInfo
                });
            });
        });
    };
});
```

5. Update "`mainApp.js`" & inject "`registerStateApp`" in your main application

   ```js
   angular.module("mainApp", [
     "ui.router",
     "registerStateApp"
   ]);

   angular.module("mainApp").config([
     "$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$registerStateProvider",
     function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $registerStateProvider) {
       
       $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
       
       //registerStateApp
       $registerStateProvider.$get();
       
       //your main application routes
       $stateProvider
         .state("/", {
           url: "/",
           templateUrl: "/Application/Partials/home.html"
         });
     }
   ]);
   ```
6. Create your sub-modules

   ```js
   angular.module("module1", []);

   angular.module("module1").config(["$registerStateProvider",
     function($registerStateProvider) {

       //This is your routing in sub module
       var stateProvider = [{
         name: "module1",
         state: "module1.page1",
         url: "/module1",
         views: {
           "module1": {
             templateUrl: "/Application/Modules/Module1/Partials/page1.html"
           }
         }
       }];

       $registerStateProvider.$set(stateProvider);
     }
   ]);

   //module2
   angular.module("module2", []);

   angular.module("module2").config(["$registerStateProvider",
     function($registerStateProvider) {
       var stateProvider = [{
         name: "module2",
         state: "module2.page1",
         url: "/module2",
         views: {
           "module2": {
             templateUrl: "/Application/Modules/Module2/Partials/page1.html"
           }
         }
       }];

       $registerStateProvider.$set(stateProvider);
     }
   ]);
   ```
7. Create sub-module main view

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html ng-app="module1">

   <head>
     <title>module1</title>
   </head>

   <body>
     <h1>This is module1</h1>
     <button ui-sref="module2.page1">go to module2 page 1</button>

     <div ui-view="module1"></div>
   </body>

   </html>

   <!--module2-->

   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html ng-app="module2">

   <head>
     <title>module2</title>
   </head>

   <body>
     <h1>This is module2</h1>
     <button ui-sref="module1.page1">go to module1 page 1</button>

     <div ui-view="module2"></div>
   </body>

   </html>
   ```
8. Add your sub-modules state in your main app "`mainApp.js`"

   ```js
   angular.module("mainApp", [
     "ui.router",
     "registerStateApp",
     "module1",
     "module2"
   ]);

   angular.module("mainApp").config([
     "$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$registerStateProvider",
     function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $registerStateProvider) {
       $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
       $registerStateProvider.$get();
       $stateProvider
         .state("/", {
           url: "/",
           templateUrl: "/Application/Partials/home.html"
         })
         .state("module1", {
           url: "/module1",
           templateUrl: "/Application/Modules/Module1/index.html"
         })
         .state("module2", {
           url: "/module2",
           templateUrl: "/Application/Modules/Module2/index.html"
         });
     }
   ]);
   ```