# Multiple ui-view in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a ui-view which replaces whole page depending on state, the one of my view in this views is home page,which consist of a left navigation and a right container.How can i implement this home page as i already used the ui-view in the parent.

Comment: check out this [Multiple ui-view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34251255/creating-nested-route-app-in-angular-using-angular-ui-route-and-switching-betwee)

Comment: do it step by step to understand.